# INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES with google-services plugin

Tags: android, gradle

I have a big project with different build types and flavors.
It is in production already more than half of the year and I've made more then hundred updates of its version.
Today I need to implement plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' into the project and can not run application because INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES.
I'm sure problem with configuration of build types and flavors but before apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' everything was always well working. Please, help me to understand what can conflict with google-services plugin.

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
    apply plugin: 'retrolambda'
    apply plugin: 'android-apt'
    apply plugin: 'android'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
            mavenLocal()
            maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        }

        dependencies {
            classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:2.4.1'
            classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
            classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        }
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url "https://github.com/taplytics/Taplytics-Android-SDK/raw/master/AndroidStudio/" }
    }

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
        dexOptions {
            jumboMode = true
        }

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.examplepack.appp"
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 291
            versionName "1.0.1.291"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }

        signingConfigs {
            config {
                storeFile file('certificate.jks')
                storePassword 'examplepass'
                keyAlias 'appl'
                keyPassword 'examplepass'
            }
        }

        buildTypes {
            debug {
                minifyEnabled true
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
            release {
                minifyEnabled true
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                signingConfig signingConfigs.config

            }
        }
        productFlavors {
            stage {
            }
            dev {
            }
            prod {
            }

        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
        }

        lintOptions {
            checkReleaseBuilds false
            abortOnError false
        }
    }

    apt {
        arguments {
            androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
            resourcePackageName "com.examplepack.appp"
        }
    }

    retrolambda {
        jdk "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home"
        oldJdk System.getenv("JAVA6_HOME")
        javaVersion JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }

dependencies {
 .............
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a [known issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=187183) with version 1.4-beta2 or newer of the Gradle plugin.

You can use a older version for this to work

Comment: Tanks.
Now I see it happens only after I put these two rows
**classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.4.0-beta3'** and **apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'** exactly as google recomends https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client.
I tried to use older version: **classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0** and **com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0** but have the same error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES

Answer (score 0):

I've been dealing with this issue for a while. I decided to try every combination of com.android.tools.build:gradle and com.google.gms:google-services.

This work for me:

- Project level:

`com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1`
`com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.1`

- App Level:

`com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0`

I also upgraded Google Repository and Sdk Tools to latest versions. I'm using Android Studio 1.4.